# spring boot graphql connection reset by peer

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, graphql, httpclient

I'm trying to request a SaaS CMS server that exposes some graphQl endpoints using spring boot and its graphQl built in support.

the application is deployed as a docker image in kube at AWS.

after some idle time with the server, I receive this error message:

```
2022-09-12 08:23:34.854  WARN 1 --- [or-http-epoll-3] r.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect    : The connection observed an error, the request cannot be retried as the headers/body were sent

io.netty.channel.unix.Errors$NativeIoException: readAddress(..) failed: Connection reset by peer

org.springframework.graphql.client.GraphQlTransportException: GraphQlTransport error: readAddress(..) failed: Connection reset by peer; nested exception is 
io.netty.channel.unix.Errors$NativeIoException: readAddress(..) failed: Connection reset by peer; nested exception is 
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: readAddress(..) failed: Connection reset by peer; nested exception is 
io.netty.channel.unix.Errors$NativeIoException: readAddress(..) failed: Connection reset by peer
    at org.springframework.graphql.client.DefaultGraphQlClient$DefaultRequestSpec.lambda$null$1(DefaultGraphQlClient.java:161) ~[spring-graphql-1.0.1.jar!/:1.0.1]
    at org.springframework.graphql.client.DefaultGraphQlClient$DefaultRequestSpec$$Lambda$2392.000000009C0E8470.apply(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.lambda$onErrorResume$32(Mono.java:3809) ~[reactor-core-3.4.18.jar!/:3.4.18]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono$$Lambda$2393.000000009C0E91A0.apply(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:94) ~[reactor-core-3.4.18.jar!/:3.4.18]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onError(FluxMapFuseable.java:142) ~[reactor-core-3.4.18.jar!/:3.4.18]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onError(FluxMapFuseable.java:142) ~[reactor-core-3.4.18.jar!/:3.4.18]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:172) ~[reactor-core-3.4.18.jar!/:3.4.18]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onError(Operators.java:2063) ~[reactor-core-3.4.18.jar!/:3.4.18]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onError(FluxOnAssembly.java:544) ~[reactor-core-3.4.18.jar!/:3.4.18]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onError(FluxMap.java:134) ~[reactor-core-3.4.18.jar!/:3.4.18]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:106) ~[reactor-core-3.4.18.jar!/:3.4.18]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.error(Operators.java:198) ~[reactor-core-3.4.18.jar!/:3.4.18]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoErrorSupplied.subscribe(MonoErrorSupplied.java:56) ~[reactor-core-3.4.18.jar!/:3.4.18]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400) ~[reactor-core-3.4.18.jar!/:3.4.18]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:103) ~[reactor-core-3.4.18.jar!/:3.4.18]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:222) ~[reactor-core-3.4.18.jar!/:3.4.18]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:222) ~[reactor-core-3.4.18.jar!/:3.4.18]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:222) ~[reactor-core-3.4.18.jar!/:3.4.18]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onError(MonoNext.java:93) ~[reactor-core-3.4.18.jar!/:3.4.18]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyMain.onError(MonoFlatMapMany.java:204) ~[reactor-core-3.4.18.jar!/:3.4.18]
    at reactor.core.publisher.SerializedSubscriber.onError(SerializedSubscriber.java:124) ~[reactor-core-3.4.18.jar!/:3.4.18]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenMainSubscriber.whenError(FluxRetryWhen.java:225) ~[reactor-core-3.4.18.jar!/:3.4.18]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenOtherSubscriber.onError(FluxRetryWhen.java:274) ~[reactor-core-3.4.18.jar!/:3.4.18]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:415) ~[reactor-core-3.4.18.jar!/:3.4.18]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:251) ~[reactor-core-3.4.18.jar!/:3.4.18]
    at reactor.core.publisher.EmitterProcessor.drain(EmitterProcessor.java:491) ~[reactor-core-3.4.18.jar!/:3.4.18]
    at reactor.core.publisher.EmitterProcessor.tryEmitNext(EmitterProcessor.java:299) ~[reactor-core-3.4.18.jar!/:3.4.18]
    at reactor.core.publisher.SinkManySerialized.tryEmitNext(SinkManySerialized.java:100) ~[reactor-core-3.4.18.jar!/:3.4.18]
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalManySink.emitNext(InternalManySink.java:27) ~[reactor-core-3.4.18.jar!/:3.4.18]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenMainSubscriber.onError(FluxRetryWhen.java:190) ~[reactor-core-3.4.18.jar!/:3.4.18]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.error(MonoCreate.java:201) ~[reactor-core-3.4.18.jar!/:3.4.18]
    at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$HttpObserver.onUncaughtException(HttpClientConnect.java:399) ~[reactor-netty-http-1.0.19.jar!/:1.0.19]
    at reactor.netty.ReactorNetty$CompositeConnectionObserver.onUncaughtException(ReactorNetty.java:670) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.19.jar!/:1.0.19]
    at reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider$DisposableAcquire.onUncaughtException(DefaultPooledConnectionProvider.java:205) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.19.jar!/:1.0.19
]
    ght(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:424) ~[netty-transport-4.1.77.Final.jar!/:
4.1.77.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerAdapter.exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerAdapter.java:92) ~[netty-transport-4.1.77.Final.jar!/:4.1.77.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$1.fireExceptionCaught(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:145) ~[netty-transport-4.1.77.Final.jar!/:4.1.77.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.exceptionCaught(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:143) ~[netty-transport-4.1.77.Final.jar!/:4.1.77.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.exceptionCaught(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:231) ~[netty-transport-4.1.77.Final.jar!/:4.1.77.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:302) ~[netty-transport-4.1.77.Final.jar!/:4.1.77.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:281) ~[netty-transport-4.1.77.Final.jar!/:4.1.77.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:273) ~[netty-transport-4.1.77.Final.jar!/:4.1.77.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.exceptionCaught(SslHandler.java:1104) ~[netty-handler-4.1.77.Final.jar!/:4.1.77.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:302) ~[netty-transport-4.1.77.Final.jar!/:4.1.77.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:281) ~[netty-transport-4.1.77.Final.jar!/:4.1.77.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:273) ~[netty-transport-4.1.77.Final.jar!/:4.1.77.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.exceptionCaught(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1377) ~[netty-transport-4.1.77.Final.jar!/:4.1.77.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:302) ~[netty-transport-4.1.77.Final.jar!/:4.1.77.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:281) ~[netty-transport-4.1.77.Final.jar!/:4.1.77.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireExceptionCaught(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:907) ~[netty-transport-4.1.77.Final.jar!/:4.1.77.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.handleReadException(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:728) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.77.Final.jar!/:
4.1.77.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:826) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.77.Final.jar!/:
4.1.77.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:487) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.77.Final.jar!/:4.1.77.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:385) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.77.Final.jar!/:4.1.77.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:995) ~[netty-common-4.1.77.Final.jar!/:4.1.77.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.77.Final.jar!/:4.1.77.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.77.Final.jar!/:4.1.77.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
        
    Caused by: org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: readAddress(..) failed: Connection reset by peer; nested exception is 
io.netty.channel.unix.Errors$NativeIoException: readAddress(..) failed: Connection reset by peer
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.lambda$wrapException$9(ExchangeFunctions.java:141) ~[spring-webflux-5.3.20.jar!/:
5.3.20]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ Request to POST null [DefaultWebClient]
Original Stack Trace:
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.lambda$wrapException$9(ExchangeFunctions.java:141) ~[spring-webflux-5.3.20.jar!/:
5.3.20]
        
2022-09-12 08:23:35.016 ERROR 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] tandardApiResponseEntityExceptionHandler : An unhandled exception occurred java.io.IOException: Broken pipe

org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:353) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flushByteBuffer(OutputBuffer.java:783) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.append(OutputBuffer.java:688) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:388) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:366) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingOutputStream.write(StreamUtils.java:287) ~[spring-core-5.3.20.jar!/:5.3.20]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator._flushBuffer(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:2171) ~[jackson-core-2.13.3.jar!/:2.13.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator.writeString(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:520) ~[jackson-core-2.13.3.jar!/:2.13.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StringSerializer.serialize(StringSerializer.java:41) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar!/:2.13.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar!/:2.13.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:774) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar!/:2.13.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar!/:2.13.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar!/:2.13.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:774) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar!/:2.13.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar!/:2.13.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar!/:2.13.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:774) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar!/:2.13.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar!/:2.13.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(IndexedListSerializer.java:119) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar!/:2.13.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serialize(IndexedListSerializer.java:79) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar!/:2.13.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serialize(IndexedListSerializer.java:18) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar!/:2.13.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar!/:2.13.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:774) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar!/:2.13.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar!/:2.13.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar!/:2.13.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar!/:2.13.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1518) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar!/:2.13.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:1007) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar!/:2.13.3]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:456) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar!/:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:104) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar!/:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:290)
```

I'm using:

- spring boot 2.7.3
- openjdk version "11" 2018-09-25
  OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11+28)
  OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11+28, mixed mode)
- my pom.xml file:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.3</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<groupId>some.group.Id</groupId>
<artifactId>some.artifact.id</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>some name</name>


<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <jakarta.validation-api.version>3.0.2</jakarta.validation-api.version>
</properties>


<dependencies>

    <!-- spring boot GraphQL dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-graphql</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty-resolver-dns-native-macos</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.80.Final</version>
        <classifier>osx-aarch_64</classifier>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jakarta.validation-api.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- test dependencies -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.graphql</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-graphql-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

here is my configuration class to build the graphQlClient

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfig {

    @Bean
    ContributionProperties contributionProperties() {

        return new ContributionProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    HttpGraphQlClient httpGraphQlClient(ContributionProperties contributionProperties) {

        String url = contributionProperties.getUrl();
        Objects.requireNonNull(url, "cms.url must be set");

        String apiToken = contributionProperties.getApiToken();
        Objects.requireNonNull(apiToken, "cms.api.token must be set");

        ConnectionProvider provider = cmsProvider(contributionProperties);

        return HttpGraphQlClient.builder()
                                .webClient(builder -> webClientBuilder(provider))
                                .headers(headers -> headers.setBearerAuth(apiToken))
                                .url(url)
                                .build();
    }

    @NonNull
    private ConnectionProvider cmsProvider(ContributionProperties contributionProperties) {

        return ConnectionProvider.builder("cms provider")
                                 .maxConnections(contributionProperties.getMaxConnections())
                                 .maxIdleTime(Duration.ofSeconds(contributionProperties.getMaxIdleTime()))
                                 .maxLifeTime(Duration.ofSeconds(contributionProperties.getMaxLifeTime()))
                                 .pendingAcquireTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(contributionProperties.getPendingAcquireTimeout()))
                                 .evictInBackground(Duration.ofSeconds(contributionProperties.getEvictInBackgroundTimeout()))
                                 .build();
    }

    @NonNull
    private WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder(ConnectionProvider provider) {

        return WebClient.builder()
                        .clientConnector(httpConnector(provider));
    }

    @NonNull
    private ReactorClientHttpConnector httpConnector(ConnectionProvider provider) {

        return new ReactorClientHttpConnector(HttpClient.create(provider));
    }

}
```

and here is how the graphQlClient is used to fetch data from the server

```
 private MyClass getResponse(String graphQlQuery) {

    return httpGraphQlClient.document(graphQlQuery)
                            .execute()
                            .map(response -> response.toEntity(MyClass.class))
                            .block();
}
```

Comment: hi I'm hitting this error too, were you able to fix this please?